# webpack module.hot.accept error with typescript not accepting array of strings TS2345

Tags: typescript, webpack

From the docs at https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/#accept it says `accept` takes a string or array of strings, but I'm still getting error below

> Argument of type 'string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'string'.  TS2345

```
if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept(
    [
      './views/Foo',
      './views/Bar',
      './views/Baz'
    ],
    myCallback
  )
}
```